# Remove all lines, where (length <= 10 AND digitsOnly ) OR (length <= 8 AND lowerCaseLetters only)

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I would like to know a bash command that removes all lines from a file for which one of the following is true:
- only digits AND equal to or shorter than 10 characters
- only lowercase letters (a-z, no special ones like umlaut) AND equal to or shorter than 8 characters

I figured out that sed is the right tool for this, but I can't get the right syntax together.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You see, this is not a code delivery service here, where people drop their requirements and other people do the work ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `grep`:

```
grep -vE '^[[:digit]]{1,10}$|^[[:lower:]]{1,8}$' file
```

Or `sed` with same regexes:

```
sed -E '/^[[:digit:]]{1,10}$/d;/^[[:lower:]]{1,8}$/d' file
```

Comment: That will fail in locales where `a-z` = `aAbBcC...z`, for example. I'd normally recommend a character class but idk if that'd be affected by the presence of an umlaut.

Comment: I would prepend `LC_ALL=C` to the above commands to address the case of funky locales.